# ReferenceError: can't find variable: FileReader in Safari 5.1.7 browser for windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I'm using cropper plugin for cropping images on my page. But, This is  not working in safari 5.1.7 & I get this error(ReferenceError: can't find variable: FileReader). I googled about this. Then, i found answer that safari will not support FileReader. Though, I couldn't move farward. What i have to do? I'm using the below code.

```
angular.module('app', ['uiCropper']).controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
$scope.myImage = '';
$scope.myCroppedImage = '';
var handleFileSelect = function(evt) {
    var file = evt.currentTarget.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(evt) {
        $scope.$apply(function($scope) {
            $scope.myImage = evt.target.result;
        });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
};
angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileInput')).on('change', handleFileSelect);});
```

Comment: This browser's last update was made in 2012, five years ago (or a century for the web). **Do not use it anymore !** Apple has stopped all support for it, so yes, you'll miss new APIs, but it's nothing compared to all the **security patches** you are missing.

Comment: Thank you Kaiido :) Is it possible overcoming that issue?

Comment: What issue ? The fact that you are using an dangerous and compromised software on your computer ? Sure, just uninstall it. If you are talking about the FileReader issue, it is supported in all active versions of Safari, so there is no issue.